# Textview onclick not working as expercted

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, onclicklistener

I have a textview inside my list view and i use a custom adapter to create `listview` and i have a textview and when i click on textview i want to change the text inside of it, It works fine for one row and if its became more than one row it wont work well coz every time i click first row its change the text in last row all the time it change the value at last row this is the code i am using

```
viewHolder.txtCommentLike = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_comment_view_like);

viewHolder.txtCommentLike
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                                viewHolder.txtCommentLike
                                        .setText("some string");


                        }
                    }

                });
```

[image]
click of helighted text but the it will update one bellow it, please can somebody tell me why is that

PS :

Adapter code

```
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        if (inflater == null) {

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        convertView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.component_comment_view_comment_row, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtCommentLike = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_comment_view_like);
           convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: Use v.setText instead of viewHolder.txtCommentLike.setText("some string");

Comment: Could you post your adapter code ? Are you sure that you are creating new instance of EditText in getView()? instead of passing reference of one object to holders ?

Comment: @user3455363 i added the adapter getview code

Comment: @bean_droid already did that not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found a Answer i was make `ViewHolder` class globally so making that local variable solve the problem

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ........
```

This solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think its` OnClickListener did not fired.

You can try to set

`clickable = "true"` to top layout-view of the list item layout..

Comment: Alright. Lets narrow our scope.


The first one try to make toast instead of changing text of button.
And we will make sure if it is fired up.

If so, then we will try to change its text via selector by using xmls.

Comment: the button click event working fine , i check it with by debugging the code the problem was its update the textview at the bottom not the one i clicked

Comment: can you replace your mViewHolder.txtCommentLike.setText("somestring"); with ((TextView)v)..setText("somestring");